# Xcode • Swift 5: How to share a CoreData store between multiple Targets?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, cloudkit

**Context**

I am using `CoreData` for persistency in my app and am planning to add a `Widget` to it as well, which needs access to the data stored in `CoreData`.

I already found out, that I have to add both `Targets` to the same `AppGroup`. However, I did not find anything about how to create the `CoreData Store` inside the shared container using SwiftUI without an `AppDelegate`.

---

**Code**

```swift
// Persistence.swift

import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController() // Singleton
    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer // CloudKit Container

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MainStorage")
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            // Todo: Handle Error
        })
    }
}
```

---

**Question:**

- How can I access the `CloudKit Store` from both `Targets`?
- As you can see, the App uses `CloudKit` by utilising the `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. Does the `CoreData` changes (moving the `Store` into the `AppGroup`) have any effect on the `CloudKit` side?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/core-data-app-extension-data-sharing/